# Android media scan not running second time

Tags: android, path, sd-card, android-mediascanner

I am working on a code that could scan the specific folder, when picture is taken, I used the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
//intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/ghost/" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
startActivityForResult(
Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
```

It works fine, but when I exit the app and start the app again, scan is not performed, what could be the issue?

Help needed!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/ghost/" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`

i used

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to have it scan a specific file.

**Set file path**
String sdPicPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/image.png";

**or if I have an albumn**
String sdPicPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "AlbumName/image.png";

**Create a File**
File CheckForAlbum = new File(sdAlbumPath);

**Have MediaScan scan the specific file.**
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(CheckForFile1)));